Azure bot, TTS not heard on Telegram bot
I have an azure bot connected to Telegram.
I used MS Speech SDK to do a TTS that works. I can also hear the text being read while testing it on the Emulator, but I don't hear anything on the Telegram Channel.
Is this a Channel issue or something I am missing. Any help ?
